# Best approach to become a scrum master?

Tags: scrum-master

I want to start my career as Scrum master and all I need is your valuable suggestions like how to start and what need to keep in the mind while learning. I worked on development side for three months and came to know about scrum etc.., Which is the best scrum org for certification?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Unfortunately, your question is too broad for this site. There are too many possible answers and good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: For now, I am looking for the basic knowledge and understanding of scrum. What are the certifications, training etc.Is there any website to surf for the information? If you have any website or videos related to this pls pass it to me. Sergey

Comment: First of all: the Bible of Scrum - [Scrumguide](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v1/Scrum-Guide-US.pdf#zoom=100). Second: there are two most famous Scrum organization - [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/) and [Scrum Alliance](https://www.scrumalliance.org/). Take a look at their sites. [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/) has a special section dedicated to your question: [Ways to learn about Scrum](https://www.scrum.org/Assessments/Ways-to-learn-about-Scrum).

Comment: Thanks Sergey for your inputs. Share your social media id. I will connect with you in offline. I am new to this stackexchange!!

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer to your question, but my answer will be based only by my own experience. Other users might came to Scrum Master by another ways.

- **Previous experience** First of all, by my strong opinion, three months of software development experience is not enough. Despite the fact that Scrum Master is manager position, it required understanding of specific of software development. It is impossible to understand all the nuances of development during 3 months. As Scrum Master you will facilitate a team and remove impedances. It is impossible to do, if you not understand software development very well. **You should know developers needs.** Only by working as developer you could get this experience. (This is only my opinion).
- **Fundamental Theoretical Knowledge** As I said in comment, **[The Scrum Guide](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v1/Scrum-Guide-US.pdf#zoom=100) is the Bible of Scrum.** You should know and understand it well. My recommendations: read it several times on your native language and then read it several times on English. Your can find all version of The Scrum Guide on [its site](http://www.scrumguides.org/).
- **Theoretical Knowledge** But The Scrum Guide is not enough to implement Scrum in real life. Scrum is adaptive methodology. It's mean, that **Scrum didn't prescribe how to do everything**. There are a lot of sites and books where you can find this "missed" knowledge. Here you can find a lists of books for all Scrum roles:

  [Suggested Reading for Scrum Master Role](https://www.scrum.org/Courses/Professional-Scrum-Master/PSM-Subject-Areas)

  [Suggested Reading for Product Owner Role](https://www.scrum.org/Courses/Professional-Scrum-Product-Owner/PSPO-Subject-Areas)

  [Suggested Reading for Developer Role](https://www.scrum.org/Courses/Professional-Scrum-Developer/PSD-Subject-Areas)

  Also, you can find a lot of interesting articles on [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/) and [Scrum Alliance](https://www.scrumalliance.org/) portals.

  But remember, all things (that you will read on these books) may or may not work in your case. It depends on you, your team, your company, business conditions and many other things. Only in Scrum Guide you can find "absolute truth" :-) All other books just give you advices, that may not work in your case. [*Phrase about "absolute truth" sounds like sermon in the sect :-)*]
- **Practice** And of course, **practice is the best teacher**. Scrum theory is very easy, but to implement it in real life is very difficult challenge. Scrum is empirical process, so practice is everything in Scrum. Do not be afraid to experiment. **Trial and error method is Scrum way of solving problems**
- **Community** You will not find all answers (on questions that you will meet in your practice) in books. So, you should took active part in community life (like [PMSE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/), [Scrum.org Community](https://www.scrum.org/Community), [Scrum Alliance Community](https://www.scrumalliance.org/community), Real life meetings and so on). **Don't be affraid to ask questions**. There are no stupid questions at all.
- **Training** By my opinion, it will be better if you will go to training, when you already will have enough practice in Scrum. In that case, you can not only receive basic knowledge about Scrum, but also ask your coach about real questions from your practice.

  There are two most famous Scrum training providers: [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/Courses) and [Scrum Allience](https://www.scrumalliance.org/courses-events/course). I passed Scrum.org training. But it's a matter of taste.
- **Certification** When you will have enough knowledge and experience, you can try to pass one of Scrum certification.

  The same as with training, there are two main certification provider: [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/Assessments) and [Scrum Allience](https://www.scrumalliance.org/certifications). I passed PSM I from Scrum.org, but you can choose another one. Take a look to the question with comparison of these two certification: [Which Scrum certification provider is most widely recognized or accepted?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/which-scrum-certification-provider-is-most-widely-recognized-or-accepted)

  During passing PSM I, most big problem for me was "language barrier". As you can see, my english is rather poor. So, it was hard to translate questions fast. I passed PSM I only from second attempt, because during my first attempt time ended faster, than I answered all the questions. But the questions themselves were not very difficult.

---

P.S. Point of view to this question:

- from Scrum.org: [Ways to learn about Scrum](https://www.scrum.org/Assessments/Ways-to-learn-about-Scrum).
- from Scrum Allience: [Learn About Scrum](https://www.scrumalliance.org/why-scrum).

Comment: Thanks for your input man!! You covered beyond my questions. Pls share your contact details to this mail id : madhu812@outlook.com. I want to discuss my situation with you and your suggestions are greatly appreciated!! Hoping the best from you.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to find every information you need under the following link:

https://www.scrumalliance.org/certifications

That organisation offers two-day long courses where you learn the basics of Scrum, and provides a one year long certificate.

Some more link:

[Which Scrum certification provider is most widely recognized or accepted?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/which-scrum-certification-provider-is-most-widely-recognized-or-accepted)

[Is Certified Scrum Master valuable?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/is-certified-scrum-master-valuable)